# Bool predicate causes zero rows count

Tags: swift, core-data, nspredicate

When i try to execute CoreData fetch request, i get correct number of rows.

```
let req = Track.fetchRequest()
return try context.count(for: req)

// result: 81
```

It works:

[image: SQLite browser request]

When i try to add bool condition,

```
let req = Track.fetchRequest()
req.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "isSentToServer = NO")
return try context.count(for: req)

// result: 0
```

it doesn't. Result it always **0** (but it still should be **81**) whatever i try:

```
NSPredicate(format: "isSentToServer = %i", NSNumber(value: false))
NSPredicate(format: "isSentToServer = %@", NSNumber(value: false))
NSPredicate(format: "isSentToServer = 0")
NSPredicate(format: "isSentToServer = %@", false)
NSPredicate(format: "isSentToServer = %@", 0)
NSPredicate(format: "isSentToServer != YES")
NSPredicate(format: "isSentToServer == NO")
NSPredicate(format: "isSentToServer == %@", "NO")
```

NOTE: `isSentToServer` is a correctly recognized attribute, changing case or adding `Z` won't help.

Are there any changes tons of Swift Tutorial authors are unaware of?

EDIT: `Track` class is auto-generated by Core Model entity editor, and isSentToServer data type is `Bool` ("Boolean" in editor) (not `Bool?`)

**UPDATE**

Here is output from my test code with `-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1` as suggested (predicate: `isSentToServer != YES`):

```
CoreData: sql: SELECT TBL_NAME FROM SQLITE_MASTER WHERE TBL_NAME = 'Z_METADATA'
CoreData: sql: pragma recursive_triggers=1
CoreData: sql: pragma journal_mode=wal
CoreData: sql: SELECT Z_VERSION, Z_UUID, Z_PLIST FROM Z_METADATA
CoreData: sql: SELECT TBL_NAME FROM SQLITE_MASTER WHERE TBL_NAME = 'Z_METADATA'
CoreData: sql: SELECT TBL_NAME FROM SQLITE_MASTER WHERE TBL_NAME = 'Z_MODELCACHE'
CoreData: sql: SELECT TBL_NAME FROM SQLITE_MASTER WHERE TBL_NAME = 'ACHANGE'
CoreData: sql: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ZTRACK
CoreData: annotation: total count request execution time: 0.0004s for count of 90.
Total track objects: 90
CoreData: sql: SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT t0.Z_PK) FROM ZTRACK t0 WHERE  t0.ZISSENTTOSERVER <> ? 
CoreData: annotation: total count request execution time: 0.0005s for count of 0.
Track objects pending upload: 0
```

For `= NO` and other "equal" cases it generates SQL `"= ?"` instead

How do i create `Track` objects?

```
let track = Track(context: context) // context is from AppDelegate, auto-generated by Xcode
// set up some properties
// not assigning any isSentToServer value explicitly
context.save() // no errors
```

EDIT 2: Note, i've tried "Erase data" of iPhone 6 simulator in my Xcode, and re-created my Track objects, still the second request returns zero rows count.

Xcode: Version 10.2 (10E125)

Targeting iOS SDK/version: 11.0 or 12.2, no difference

```
$ xcodebuild -showsdks
iOS SDKs:
    iOS 12.2                        -sdk iphoneos12.2

iOS Simulator SDKs:
    Simulator - iOS 12.2            -sdk iphonesimulator12.2
```

Comment: The predicate programming guide states that for a Boolean value you should use something like `"someAttribute == YES"`. One thing I don't see in your list is `"isSentToServer == NO"`. Try that.

Comment: `"isSentToServer = NO"` should work for a boolean attribute (`=`  and `==` are treated identically in a predicate).

Comment: Just for sake of completeness, update your question showing the entity declaration clearly showing how the `isSentToServer` attribute is declared.

Comment: My iOS app in Simulator shows result 0 for second request, i am sure. I've tried to swap order of requests (with and without predicate), but it makes no difference. I do these requests from `viewWillAppear()` and report with `print()`. I use same context, but new FetchRequest for every call.

Comment: Activate Core Data debugging (launch argument `-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 3`, see https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/TroubleshootingCoreData.html) and inspect the output.

Comment: Thanks, but how to fix `<> ?` operator? Is it wrong?

Comment: Is that the debug output for "isSentToServer = NO" ?

Comment: @MartinR Provided output is for `!= YES`. For `= NO` and all others, it outputs `= ?` in SQL instead. As i understand, `?` is a placeholder and the problem is in the actual value..

Comment: Did you set a default value for `isSentToServer`?

Comment: There used to be an issue with attribute names that began with "is", a result of subtleties with how Key Value Coding works in Objective-C.  It may be the weirdness you are observing is related to that?  Can you try with a different attribute name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a comment with workaround.

What helped, is combination of:

1. set `track.isSentToServer = false` for *new* objects *explicitly*
2. set `track.time = Date()` for *new* objects *excplicitly* (i do not use this field in predicate) (generated type is: `Date?`)

As a result, predicate works.

Although, my expectations were pretty logic:

1. `false` must be default as it has `Bool` type (not `Bool?`).
2. `nil` must be default value for `Date?` attribute and it must not affect predicates that don't mention it.

I was not able to find information is this behavior is documented or not.

Comment: In my experience a boolean attribute can have three values: true, false and null. A fetch predicate and a filter predicate handle the null value differently. Solution: always set a default value for boolean attributes in the data model.

Comment: What experience may i ask? I see you code on apple, i just never saw boolean to have three possible values, especially in SQL. Only for nullables in specific frameworks, like `bool?` in Swift or C#, but i have `bool` in auto-generated entity class. In SQL/SQLite, bool fields are tinyint or integer and 0 is considered false, not null AFAIK?

Comment: The value of an optional Boolean attribute can be `nil`. The default default value in the data model is None.